# Как по клику получить текст из div?

Tags: javascript

```html
<div id="name">
  <div>Name1</div>
  <div>Name2</div>
  <div>Name3</div>
  <div>Name4</div>
  <div>Name5</div>
</div>
```

Как получить именно текст, который содержится в диве по которому произошёл клик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#name > div").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(el.textContent);
}));
```

```html
<div id="name">
  <div>Name1</div>
  <div>Name2</div>
  <div>Name3</div>
  <div>Name4</div>
  <div>Name5</div>
</div>
```